# Not able to sort the unicode numbers in python

Tags: python

Following is out from python shell:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'English_United States.1252'
>>> c = [u'9', u'9', u'54', u'51', u'48', u'48', u'47', u'46', u'46', u'45', u'44', u'44', u'43', u'43', u'43', u'42', u'42', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'40', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'37', u'37', u'37', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'34', u'34', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'32', u'32', u'32', u'31', u'31', u'31', u'30', u'30', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'26', u'26', u'25', u'25', u'25', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'23', u'2', u'17', u'16', u'12', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0']
>>> sorted(c,locale.strcoll)
[u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'12', u'16', u'17', u'2', u'23', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'25', u'25', u'25', u'26', u'26', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'30', u'30', u'31', u'31', u'31', u'32', u'32', u'32', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'34', u'34', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'37', u'37', u'37', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'40', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'42', u'42', u'43', u'43', u'43', u'44', u'44', u'45', u'46', u'46', u'47', u'48', u'48', u'51', u'54', u'9', u'9']
```

Output is not sorted . There is a `u'16', u'17', u'2'` and then `u'23'`.

Don't know what is going on here. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Search for "natural sort".

Comment: Output is perfectly sorted. In lexicographical order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fascinating how much is packed into the elegant and simple-looking `sorted()`. From the docs, http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted :

> *key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default
>   value is None (compare the elements directly).*

So one can cast the element in the list as such while calling `sorted()`:

```
>>> c = [u'9', u'9', u'54', u'51', u'48', u'48', u'47', u'46', u'46', u'45', u'44', u'44', u'43', u'43', u'43', u'42', u'42', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'40', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'37', u'37', u'37', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'34', u'34', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'32', u'32', u'32', u'31', u'31', u'31', u'30', u'30', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'26', u'26', u'25', u'25', u'25', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'23', u'2', u'17', u'16', u'12', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0']
>>> sorted(c, key=int)
[u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'2', u'9', u'9', u'12', u'16', u'17', u'23', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'25', u'25', u'25', u'26', u'26', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'30', u'30', u'31', u'31', u'31', u'32', u'32', u'32', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'34', u'34', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'37', u'37', u'37', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'40', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'42', u'42', u'43', u'43', u'43', u'44', u'44', u'45', u'46', u'46', u'47', u'48', u'48', u'51', u'54']
```

Alternatively, there is a `natsort` library, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort,

```
>>> import natsort
>>> c = [u'9', u'9', u'54', u'51', u'48', u'48', u'47', u'46', u'46', u'45', u'44', u'44', u'43', u'43', u'43', u'42', u'42', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'40', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'37', u'37', u'37', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'34', u'34', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'32', u'32', u'32', u'31', u'31', u'31', u'30', u'30', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'26', u'26', u'25', u'25', u'25', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'23', u'2', u'17', u'16', u'12', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0']
>>> natsort.natsorted(c)
[u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'1', u'1', u'1', u'2', u'9', u'9', u'12', u'16', u'17', u'23', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'24', u'25', u'25', u'25', u'26', u'26', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'29', u'30', u'30', u'31', u'31', u'31', u'32', u'32', u'32', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'33', u'34', u'34', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'35', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'36', u'37', u'37', u'37', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'38', u'40', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'41', u'42', u'42', u'43', u'43', u'43', u'44', u'44', u'45', u'46', u'46', u'47', u'48', u'48', u'51', u'54']
```

especially when your elements contains some nondigit strings.

```
>>> x = ['foo12', 'foo1', 'foo2','foo24']
>>> natsort.natsorted(x)
['foo1', 'foo2', 'foo12', 'foo24']
```

Comment: I just added an answer about `natsort`, but I'll delete mine and upvote yours instead.

Comment: You don't need the `key=lambda y: y.lower()` in this example, because there are only numbers in the string.  Just `natsort.natsorted(c)` works.

Answer (score 3):

You need to sort as numbers, not as text. Try this:

```
myList.sort(key=int)
```

The int function is run in each element before it sorts, forcing it to sort the strings as integer numbers.

Comment: Since the OP is using `sorted()`: `sorted(c, key=int)` would be closer to what is needed here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My answer as comment was before that, [but](http://bayanbox.ir/id/6622806717748254961?view) ...

Comment: @OmidRaha: You commented, not answered.

Comment: @OmidRaha, I'm pretty sure I saw this answer before I saw your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are sorted in a [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). The output is expected when you know that this is how the sort function works.

It appears that what you are looking for is a natural sort. I would suggest taking a look at the [natsort package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort).

Alternatively you could implement your own comparison operation for the sort.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want them sorted in numerical order. You can try something like this. `c` is your list of strings from before. You have two options, first:

```
sorted_c=sorted(c, key=float)
```

Without the key function, python sorts those numbers as *strings*. Since `'10'` is *alphabetically* before `'7'` (it starts with a 1, after all), the sort function will put it *earlier* in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need a double coversion:

```
map(unicode, sorted(map(int, c)))
```

Comment: No, you don't. Not with a `key` function argument to `sorted()` and `list.sort()`.

Answer (score -1):

They are strings. Strings are sorted alphabetically. 16, 17, 2, 23 is sorted correctly for strings.